# Restoring a MySQL table back to the database

Tags: mysql

I have a trouble in restoring  MySQL table back to the database from command line. Taking backup of a table is working with mysqldump.Taking backup and restoring of a database is also working properly. I have used:

mysql -uroot -p DatabaseName TableName < path\TableName.sql

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Bijsha, welcome to Stackoverflow.  To help you please give more details, including what exactly the problem is, what error text you are getting right now and what the trouble is.  Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Ah, I think I see the problem here.

Your backup script looks fine. `tbl_name` works correctly as the optional 2nd argument.

To restore, you should simply run

```
mysql -uroot -p DatabaseName < path\TableName.sql
```

Running `man mysql` would have shown you the correct arguments and options

> mysql [options] db_name

As your backup script only contains one table, only that table will be restored into your database.

Comment: should be `-u root` and also `path/TableName.sql` .

Comment: @JohnJoe `-u` works with or without a space and OP is obviously using Windows and thus, uses backslash directory separators

Comment: It is worked for me. I have made some changes as per my server onfiguration such as **mysql -u Username -p Password -h localhost DatabaseName < path/Script_of_table.sql** [note here "/" forward slash not "\" backward]

Comment: if i  restore from backup to existing table with some data, will it be overridden? If so how to avoid it?

Comment: @VeereshP that entirely depends on what's in your backup script.

Answer (score 23):

Taking backup

```
mysqldump -u -p mydatabase table1 > database_dump.sql
```

restoring from backup flie need not include table name

```
mysql -u -p mydatabase < database_dump.sql
```

Comment: can I do the same by using a batch file?

Comment: Do you want to restore from batch file ?

Comment: I want to take backup and restore through a batch file..is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Best way to restore your database:

open **cmd** at `bin` folder

login to mysql:

```
mysql -uroot -pyour_password

show databases;

use db_name;
```

now hit source and put the complete path from address bar where your sql file is stored and hit ;

for example :

```
source db_name.sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy your db.sql file to your Mysql Server if you are in a remote machine:

**$rsync -Cravzp --progress db.sql user@192.168.10.1:/home/user**

Now you can go to your remote server as:

**$ssh -l user 192.168.10.1**

In the Mysql Server you must to do this:

user@machine:~$**mysql -h localhost -u root -p**

Obs: The file db.sql must be in the same place  (/home/user).

Now type this command in you Mysql Server:

**mysql>'\'. db.sql** + Enter. Obs: Remove all ' from this command to work

Answer (score 0):

If you have a SQL backup file of whole database and you want to restore only one table in MYSQL then follow below command:

```
>> sed -n -e '/DROP TABLE.*`table_name`/,/UNLOCK TABLES/p' databases_backup_file.sql > table_backup_file.sql
```

Before restoring it, check if file is having properly extracted to restore the desire table using any of following commands.

```
>> less table_backup_file.sql
>> head table_backup_file.sql
>> tail table_backup_file.sql
```

Now you can restore the table as per below command:

```
>> mysql -uyour_user -pyour_password db_name < table_backup_file.sql
```